# How to disable synchronization of replies in a movelet

Tags: movilizer

is it possible to design a Movelet in a way that it does not send reply data when synchronizing? If so, how? 
We want to use data containers instead and the replies are only creating traffic.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it is possible to process Movelets without sending/storing replies. 
Just use the transactional="true" attribute in the Movelet tag and leave the Movelet flow via nextQuestionKey="CANCEL", instead of "END". This will result in a complete deletion of the stored replies of the already processed questions. Afterwards you will enter the Movelet at the defined initial question again.

On the other hand you can also leave the Movelet via "CANCEL" and transactional="false", which results in an uncomplete and not finalized reply set (which will not be deleted). Your new staring question is now the one you left the Movelet.

Hope this helps to smarten your scenario.

Best regards